# Middleman, Compass and Formalize

Tags: compass-sass, formalize, middleman

I have been trying to get middleman, compass and formalize to work together, but so far without too much luck.

I *did* install the Compass Formalize plugin

```
sudo gem install compass_formalize
```

... and I *did* add the obligatory require to `config.rb`

```
require "compass_formalize"
```

... but the effect is that my stylesheets *can* be located (with `@import "formalize";`
), but I don't know how to pull in the JavaScript files. Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery example:

```
cd project_dir
compass install formalize/jquery
```

`jquery.formalize.js` should be in the javascript directory specified in config.rb